# Is there a maximum value for AUC for a given value of calibration?

Tags: roc, auc, calibration

Is there an upper boundary for the AUC of a risk model that is dependent on both the model calibration and the frequency of the outcome under examination?

[Cook](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17309939) suggests that high values for discrimination can only be achieved under certain distributions of a predictor and at a certain outcome frequency when calibration is perfect. This seems at odds with my intuition that: 1) any distribution of predictors could perfectly predict the outcome of interest (e.g. split the distribution in half at the middle and assign 0's to one side and 1's to the other), and 2) discrimination should be proportional to the accuracy of calibration, while calibration is not necessarily proportional to discrimination. Tied values could upset the relationship for either, but assuming tied values of the predictor are not present, how can improved calibration result in reduced discrimination?

[image: Figure 3]
Figure: Achievable C-statistic with perfect calibration for various simulated outcome frequencies (left 10%, right 50%) and predictor distributions from Cook, NR. Use and Misuse of the Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve in Risk Prediction. Circulation. 2007 Feb 20;115(7):928-35.

The paper above references [Diamond's demonstration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Diamond%20GA%5BAuthor%5D%20perfection) of the trade off between discrimination and calibration. The values used in Diamond's example seem quite extreme. Can we take the tension of calibration and discrimination to be true in less extreme cases?